# How to skip nunit test in Jenkins using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, msbuild, nunit

I'm using the following PowerShell to run Nunit test.

```
$tests = ''
Get-ChildItem -path "." -Recurse -Include "*Test*.dll" | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -Match ".*\\bin\\Debug"} | foreach {$tests += ($_.toString() -ireplace ([regex]::Escape($env:WORKSPACE) + '\\'), ' ')}
$env:COMPLUS_Version='v4.0.0000'
Invoke-Expression "C:\Jenkins\workspace\APP\Build\NUnitForms\lib\nunit\nunit-console-x86.exe $tests /result:nunit-result.xml"
```

Basically, try to pass all test.dll files to nunit-console.exe

Is it possible to skip/ignore some of the tests of running  Anybody help how to skip/ignore nunit test using PowerShell?

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Expression`. Just put the command line you want to run, but quote the last parameter: `C:\Jenkins\workspace\APP\Build\NUnitForms\lib\nunit\nunit-console-x86.exe $tests "/result:nunit-result.xml"`.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore specific test?